# Vimeo Froogaloop events not firing on iOS

Tags: ios, vimeo, vimeo-player

I'm trying to append an element to the page when a Vimeo embed starts playing. The code I'm using is:

```
var iframe = $videoObj.find("iframe")[0],
player = $f(iframe);

function onPlayProgress(id) {           
    if(!$videoObj.find(".video-play-pause").length)
        $videoObj.append(controlHTML);
}

player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('play', onPlayProgress);
});
```

The event fires fine on desktop browsers, but it doesn't seem to fire on iOS7. I've also tried the play/pause events, but these don't work either. The ready event seems to be the only one that fires.

Is there a workaround for making the events fire or are they simply unsupported by iOS?

**UPDATE**

It seems that setting a video ID and using it with the API is what was missing to make it work on iOS (although that's not required in Chrome/Safari on desktop).

Comment: can you post the solution code? I'm having similar problems

Comment: hi, can you please show how you can "setting a video ID and using it with the API" ?

Comment: with an iframe like this i guess :
<iframe id="video-iframe" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ videoID }}?api=1;player_id=video-iframe" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>